# C++14 - Does an std::revers(ed) std::string contain a null character at the start?

Tags: c++, c++14

If I use `std::reverse` on an `std::string` variable, can I safely assume that the null character `'\0'` will be placed at the beginning of the string?

Comment: What would you be using as iterators for the string?

Comment: If you had a string that ended with a nul byte included in the string, then yes. If you did not put one at the end, don't expect it at the start.

Comment: `std::string` does not have to contain `\0` at all in its internal representation, and reversing it wouldn't change that

Comment: @MaksimSolovjov Then I don't know why my program works when I assume that there is a null character. I'm solving a weird assignment from Stroustrup's Programming: Principles and Practice. I need to read a number (up to 4 digits) as characters (I did it as a string) and then convert them into an int. Then print it out with place values (hundreds, tens, ones). When the input is 34, the place value for hundreds is 0, so I want it to display "3 tens and 4 ones" instead of "0 hundreds and 3 tens and 4 ones". This happens when I assume that the 3rd char is '\0', not '0'.

Comment: Accessing `*std::end(s)` is likely to work on many implementations but it is not guaranteed by the standard, and will in fact cause errors on other implementations.  This is because most implementations of `std::string` will keep a NUL byte past the end in order to simplify the implementations of `.data()` and `.c_str()`.  I know for a fact that dereferencing `std::end(s)` will cause errors on debug builds on certain MSVC implementations.

Comment: The nul character requirement is a C language thing.  The C++ `std::string` data type does not require a nul character for termination.

Comment: @Andy356 Er...okay, even if the string `34` *were* null-terminated, and `std::reverse` *did* preserve the `null` but move it to the beginning (which wouldn't really make sense because if the null were necessary in the first place then the reversed string would no longer be viable), how would that help you distinguish between `\0` in the "hundreds" place and `\0` in the "thousands" or "ten thousands" place?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, but it does guarantee there is one there anyway.

Comment: @KyleStrand I have an error check to disallow numbers greater than 4 digits. Also, I'm dealing with them on a character by character basis to compose the digits into an int.

Comment: Okay, but you still can't distinguish between a two-digit number and a three-digit number based on the value of the first byte in the reversed string.

Comment: @KyleStrand I only needed to reverse the string because my `for` loop was also incidentally reversing the final int output. So when the input to the loop is reversed, the output is coming out straight (unreversed?) and everything works out. :) Writing a `for` loop which gives an unreversed output needs a temporary variable and all the extra code, which I didn't want to use.

Comment: So what were you trying to use the NUL byte for (assuming it exists)?

Comment: @KyleStrand Oh god. My initial logic just seems stupid now. I was assuming that when the user enters a 3 digit number, the 4th digit place will be occupied by a NUL byte. So when I'm `cout`ing the result, I can check for the `\0` and omit the thousands place.

Comment: That's okay! I often find my initial approach to a problem is stupid in retrospect....sadly, I'm not sure that feeling will ever go away entirely.

Comment: @KyleStrand I suppose that feeling is an integral part of being a programmer. :) If you don't find your earlier attempts worse than the present ones, you haven't really progressed...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it will not contain a NUL byte (unless you put one there).  The forward iterator won't contain a NUL byte either, it will only iterate over the characters in the string itself.

The NUL byte is guaranteed to be past the end of `.c_str()` or `.data()`, however.

### Sample program:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string s = "Hello";
    std::cout << "Forwards:\n";
    for (auto i = std::begin(s), e = std::end(s); i != e; ++i) {
        std::cout << *i << ' ' << static_cast<int>(*i) << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << "Backwards:\n";
    std::reverse(std::begin(s), std::end(s));
    for (auto i = std::begin(s), e = std::end(s); i != e; ++i) {
        std::cout << *i << ' ' << static_cast<int>(*i) << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
Forwards:
H 72
e 101
l 108
l 108
o 111
Backwards:
o 111
l 108
l 108
e 101
H 72
```

Comment: Can you mention that this is because std::string keeps track of size internally, so does not actually *use* a null byte to mark the end. (And how this enables it to be used to store null characters inside of a string). I.E. that std::string is very different from c-style strings.

Comment: @zstewart It actually will have its own null byte at the end - that's why `c_str()` is O(1).

Comment: @zstewart: It sounds like you mentioned it for me, thanks.

Comment: @Barry Ok, I was mistaken on the implementation, nevermind.

Comment: The length of the string is stored internally (hence why it is possible to embed null characters in a std::string, even though c-strings cannot do this). A null character may be stored at the end by the implementation in order to facilitate O(1) access with `c_str()`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Thank you. :) I don't know what NUL, `.c_str()` or `.data()` is, but the sample program was very lucid. I'm assuming a NUL byte is '\0'? Although the answer clarified my doubt, it made my program more difficult to... program.

Comment: @Andy356: If you want a NUL byte, then you can use pointers to iterate over the characters in `.c_str()` or `.data()` safely, including the NUL byte.  You just can't use the standard `std::string` iterators.

Comment: @Barry As long as the `std::string` doesn't need to be *re-allocated* in order to append `\0`, `c_str()` would still be O(1) even if it wrote `\0` at the last-plus-one byte of the string data inside the `c_str()` function implementation.

Comment: @KyleStrand Yes and the way you guarantee that it doesn't need to be reallocated in order to append the `\0` is... to append the `\0` to start with. Otherwise, it wouldn't be O(1)...

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I don't know what you mean by that. :( I don't think I'm at that level yet. I think I should just tell the user to enter the number as 0024 or 0843 instead of 24 or 843. Then it would comply with my code without needing the null character assumption.

Comment: @Barry Only the *allocation* has to be performed in advance. This is separate from *writing* the value `\0` to that byte of memory. (I assume most or all implementations do in fact perform the `\0`-write in advance, I'm just trying to say that an implementation *could* do that lazily.)

Comment: @Andy356 If you don't know what `.c_str()` or `.data()` is, then *look up the documentation on `std::string`*.

Comment: @KyleStrand, no, `string::data()` is a const function, so cannot write to the string (doing so could introduce a data race in multithreaded programs, unless the string locks a mutex for every single operation, both const and non-const, which would be insane.). The terminator has to be there all along.

Comment: @KyleStrand Already on it. :) Never gonna waste an opportunity to learn. ;) Though I've modified my code for now...

Comment: @JonathanWakely: `const` has nothing to do with thread safety and mutexes.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, I suggest you read 17.6.5.9 [res.on.data.races] and 23.2.2 [container.requirements.dataraces]. Standard library types are required to avoid data races when calling const functions on a single object concurrently, so it must be safe for two threads to call `s.data()` or `s.c_str()` or `s[s.length()]` or any other const functions concurrently, which makes it very difficult for implementations to perform any writes in those functions (if they do make any such writes they must add sufficient synchronisation to avoid data races).

Comment: So anyway, why you're getting a lot of different answers is because for C++11 the rules for `std::string` changed.  Before C++11 you weren't guaranteed to have a C-ish closing zero.  Since C++11 you are, and in effect `c_str()` and `data()` are the same.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Indeed I was not at all thinking about thread safety (and in fact I didn't realize the library made such a guarantee). Writing NUL to a byte that is guaranteed to be NUL in every context where it's readable (e.g. via `.c_str()`) seems pretty benign, but again it doesn't really seem like a likely implementation. I just wanted to clarify that there's no algorithmic-order argument that justifies guaranteeing eagerly writing NUL to the one-past-the-end byte.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I safely assume that the null character '\0' will be placed at the beginning of the string?

No. This will only be the case if you have placed a null character as the final character of the original string.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike most containers, `std::string` actually has data *under* the `end()` iterator.  (The standard makes dereferencing `end()` still illegal, but there is really no way to avoid it).

A `std::string` of `.size()=N` has `N+1` entries, the last of which is `'\0'`.  The first `N` entries could also contain `'\0'`s, but that last one is automatically put there.

`begin()` returns an iterator to the first entry, and `end()` to one-past-the-end (effectively, to the terminating `'\0'`, but you are not allowed to check that under the standard (which means debug iterators can catch that mistake, and tell you you made it)).

Meanwhile, `.data()` and `.c_str()` return pointers to the raw buffer.  With `.c_str()` reading the `'\0'` "past the end" is legal.  Amusingly, with `.data()` it is *not* legal to read the `'\0'` past the end of the string, as only the elements that can be iterated to are allowed to be read.  It is legal under the standard, but unlikely, that there will be an uninitialized character (or even a page fault) where the `'\0'` will be until the first call to `.c_str()` occurs.  Neither are allowed to allocate in C++11.  (I make no guarantees about C++03 or earlier versions of C++).

`rbegin()` and `rend()` thus also return elements *within* the string, not counting that terminating `'\0'`, and `reverse(begin(), end())` operates again on the elements *within* the string, not counting that terminating `'\0'`.

If you do embed `'\0'` *within* the string, these do not terminate the string.  If you pass the `.c_str()` to a `const char*` API, it will presume the string is over, but the actual buffer managed by `std::string` will go past the `'\0'` you injected.  And `end()` will continue to refer to the "one past the last" element of the string, not to your `'\0'`.

Comment: So... from what I understand, when the string variable has memory allocated to it, it is always N+1 bytes instead of N bytes? And we can only access N bytes, while `std::string` uses the (N+1)th byte for its internal implementation?

Comment: @Andy356 You can only access `N` bytes *via iterators* (in theory; in practice, `assert(*str.end() == '\0');` will probably work despite being banned by the standard, as the lazy-implementation of string iterators make them thin wrappers around pointers).  You can access `N+1` bytes via `.data()` and `.c_str()`.

Comment: One more question. :D From all the answers and comments, what I understand is that if we have a `std::string` 'abcd\0', and we use `std::reverse` on it, we should get 'dcba\0'. Am I right?

Comment: @Andy356 That depends what you consider the `std::string` to be?  Did you `std::string x = "abcd\0";`?  Did you `std::string x = "abcd";`?  Did you `char const buff = "abcd"; std::string x(std::begin(buff), std::end(buff));`?  All 3 of these could be called `std::string` 'abcd\0' by *someone*, but 2 of them are different than the third.  If you want to know what code does, actually write the code and ask what it does.  You can also add your interpretation of the code and why you are doing things, but asking what pseudo code does often depends on details not included in the pseudo code.

Comment: I'm talking about `std::string x = "abcd";`

Comment: @Andy356 Then after `std::reverse(x.begin(), x.end());`, `x == "dcba"` is guaranteed to be true.

Comment: But as you mentioned, the (N+1)th byte always contains a '\0', so theoretically, if we were to look at the bytes directly in memory, there would be a \0 after the dcba, right? abcd\0 changes to dcba\0 after `std::reverse`?

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the part about `.data()`? Specifically, *"Amusingly, with `.data()` it is not legal to read the `'\0'` past the end of the string"*. I have looked both into recent drafts and C++11 IS, where both `c_str` and `data` are defined via `operator[]` and may read the all elements of the (closed!) range `[0, size()]` which seems to include the null-terminator.

Comment: @dyp Hmm. I was relying on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data), not the standard directly, when I noticed the discussion above about claimed differences from `c_str` to `data` and found it agreed.  I'd have to figure out how guaranteed `str[str.size()] == 0` is, but I can easily believe it.

Comment: Well for `str[str.size()]`, the `operator[]` spec says *"`*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`. Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type
`charT` with value `charT()`, where modifying the object leads to undefined behavior."*

Comment: @dyp aha, a C++11 change: "`data()[i] == operator[](i)` for every i in [0, size()).  (until C++11)" and "`data() + i == &operator[](i)` for every i in [0, size()].  (since C++11)".  Which explains the weasel words in the cppreference docs.  Amusingly, `data()` forces `[size()]` to return the element one-past `[size()-1]`, even though `operator[]` doesn't!

Answer (score 0):

A std::string will not contain a terminating null character, you're thinking of a null terminated char array used as a string.

Comment: It's not considered one of the elements of the string, but it **does** contain one, after all the other elements. It is guaranteed to be there if you use `s.c_str()` or `s.data()` or `s[s.length()]`